# What does "cagneries" mean ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I came about this sentence having the word **cagneries**, but couldn't find any reference for it in the dictionary : "... la maladie de la mite baveuse qui fait vantarder les pauvres gens après leurs bévues, leurs **cagneries**, leurs tares pustulantes d'infernaux..."

The English translation conceives **cagneries** as pettiness : "... the sickness oh the drooling worm that makes poor people go bragging after their blunders, their **petttiness**, their purulent blemishes..."

Does anyone know what this word mean?

Comment: Once again this is a word invented by Céline. You won't find it any dictionary and no one else but Céline uses it. It could be constructed from [*cagner*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cagner) an old colloquial word (that most people wouldn't understand nowadays) meaning "to chicken out" (so it could translate as "cowardice") but in my opinion anything goes as long it it conveys the lower social origin of the people depicted in the paragraph.

Comment: Please ponder on this passage from a scholarly article on Céline's style: *Tant sur le plan de la syntaxe que sur celui du vocabulaire, Céline se permet des libertés avec la norme, qui vont presque toutes dans le sens d’une vulgarisation de la langue, rappelant ses origines supposées (de Céline, mais aussi de la langue française) – en d’autres termes, sa langue même se veut « mimétique ». [...] Ici, le narrateur célinien s’efforce généralement de « parler » comme le peuple; et ce qu’il dit de ce dernier, les histoires qu’il campe dans son contexte, gagnent en vraisemblance.*

Comment: Merci. Comme lecteur de Céline, je repère toujours, évidemment, que la création sur un lexique déjà existant est une procédure commun à son style. Cela n'interdit pas, je crois, l'examen de ce processus de création.

Comment: Si la question porte sur le processus de formation (et non plus sur son sens comme à l'origine) alors à mon avis le mot créé par Céline est formé à partir du verbe « cagner » auquel il a ajouté le suffixe -erie qui sert à former un nom   indiquant la qualité, la caractéristique de quelque chose (voir fourberie, menterie, tricherie, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Ce mot vient sans aucun doute du mot « cagne », qui est défini dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cagne), en tant que substantif féminin.

> **A.** − Vx. Chien de mauvaise race
> ♦ Ils entrèrent dans la Cathédrale et se mirent à tout saccager, (...) jetant à leurs chiens les hosties du ciboire, disant que si c'étaient vrais dieux, elles ne se laisseraient manger par des cagnes. J. et J. Tharaud, La Chronique des frères ennemis,1929, p. 140.
>
> **B.** − P. ext., péj., vx. Femme paresseuse et méprisable.
> ♦ C'est une vraie cagne (Ac. Compl. 1842);
> ♦ ah! Cagne que tu es, je te tiens (Sue ds Lar. 19e).

Dans le langage populaire moderne, cependant, le mot « cagne » est du masculin, et ne signifie pas « chienne » mais « *chien* ». On trouve une attestation de cela dans le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cagne).

> cagne \kaɲ\ masculin ou féminin (l’usage hésite)    Mauvais chien.
> ♦ Dans la bonté des chiens il y a des bizarreries inouïes ; les disgraciés sont quelquefois les intelligents ; et, dans la même portée, il y a trois cagnes pour un bon chien. — (Carteron, Premières chasses, Papillons et oiseaux, p. 39, Hetzel, 1866.)
> ♦ Un chasseur exposa un griffon ; qu’était ce griffon ? il passait les perdrix disséminées […] la moindre chaleur le mettait sur les dents ! ce n’était plus qu’une belle cagne. — (Carteron, ib. p. 38.)

Le fait que ce mot est de registre poulaire à argotique est attesté [ici](https://www.dictionnaire.exionnaire.com/que-signifie.php?mot=cagne).

> 1. Définition     CAGNE        n.f.            Argot
> 2. Autres graphies cagne = khâgne

C'est aussi un terme régional familier.

> Larousse) cagne  nom féminin
> Définitions    Familier. Dans le sud-ouest de la France, envie de ne rien faire ; flemme
> ♦ Il faudrait que je range, mais j'ai la cagne.

En tant que synonyme de « khâgne » ce mot est de l'argot scolaire et signifie « classe de préparation à l'entrée à l'école normale supérieure ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/kh%C3%A2gne))  Arg. scol. Classe supérieure de lycée qui prépare au concours d'entrée à l'École normale supérieure, section Lettres.
> ♦ Il s'appelait Michel Riesmann et finissait sa deuxième année de khâgne (S. de Beauvoir, Mémoires d'une jeune fille rangée,1958, p. 242)

On obtient de la source précédente que « cagne » est tiré de l'argot.

> Étymol. et Hist. [1888 d'apr. Esn.]; 1905 (J. Rivière, Alain-Fournier, Correspondance, p. 48). Prob. dér. régr. de cagneux (Esn.). Une orig. par antiphrase à partir de cagne 1 qui désigne en arg. une personne paresseuse comme une chienne (A. Delvau, Dict. de la lang. verte, 1866) puis la paresse elle-même, notamment dans l'expr. avoir la cagne (L. Rigaud, Dict. de l'arg. mod., 1881) est moins probable. Fréq. abs. littér. : 22.

On trouve aussi le verbe « cagner ».

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cagner)) (XIXe siècle) Dénominal de cagne (« chienne »), d’après cagneux (« qui boite ») pour le deuxième sens. Verbe
> cagner \ka.ɲe\ intransitif 1er groupe (voir la conjugaison)
> 1.(Populaire) Faire la cagne, reculer devant une besogne difficile ou dangereuse.
> ♦ Je vous promets de ne pas instruire le Proviseur de votre conduite. − Ah ! Vous cagnez, répondis-je en employant un terme d’écolier. — (Du Camp, Mémoires d’un suicidé, 1853, p. 65)
> 2.  Boiter, se déplacer avec peine, d'un rythme irrégulier.
> Parmi la foule gesticulante et qui cagne, vers son appartement quelconque il serpenta. — (Barrès, Sous l’œil des Barbares, 1888, p. 22

- ... la maladie de la mite baveuse qui fait vantarder les pauvres gens après leurs bévues, leurs cagneries, leurs tares pustulantes d'infernaux...

> ([extrait plus complet](https://www.babelio.com/auteur/Louis-Ferdinand-Celine/2086/citations?pageN=97)) On serait né fils d'un riche planteur à Cuba Havane par exemple, tout se serait passé bien gentiment, mais on est venu chez des gougnafes, dans un coin pourri sur toutes parts, alors faut pâtir pour la caste et c'est l'injustice qui vous broye, **la maladie de la mite baveuse qui fait vantarder les pauvres gens après leurs bévues, leurs cagneries, leurs tares pustulantes d'infernaux,** que d'écouter c'est à vomir tellement qu'ils sont bas et tenaces ! Mois après mois, c'est sa nature, le paumé gratis il expie, sur le chevalet "Pro Deo", sa naissance infâme, ligoté bien étroitement avec son livret matricule, son bulletin de vote, sa face d'enflure. Tantôt c'est la Guerre ! C'est la Paix ! C'est la Reguerre ! Le Triomphe ! C'est le Grand Désastre ! Ça change rien au fond des choses !il est marron dans tous les retours. C'est lui le paillasse de l'univers... Il donnerait sa place à personne, il frétille que pour les bourreaux. Toujours à disposition de tous les fumiers de la planète ! Tout le monde lui passe sur la guenille, se fait les poigne sur sa détresse, il est gâté.

À partir des trois références suivantes,

> « ([cheylétiellose](https://www.bing.com/search?q=maladie+de+la+mite&cvid=b8ae5c4ec76746daa88918040de3e5a5&aqs=edge..69i57j0l6.4837j0j1&pglt=43&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=U531)) La cheylétiellose (mites de corps, walking dandruff) est une affection parasitaire hautement contagieuse et relativement fréquente chez les chats, les chiens et les lapins québécois. Elle est causée par un acarien (mite) microscopique… »,

> « ([mite de corps](https://centredmv.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Dermatologie-La-cheyletiellose_FR.pdf) La cheyletiellose ("mites de corps", "walking dandruff") est
> une maladie de la peau causée par un parasite qui affecte les
> chats, les chiens et les lapins. Ce parasite est un acarien
> (Cheyletiella spp.) qui est très contagieux et qui n’est pas
> spécifique d’hôte, pouvant ainsi se transférer entre
> différentes espèces animales en contact. Le parasite vit à la
> surface de la peau et se nourrit de kératine, de débris
> cutanés et de lymphe. Les cheyletielles adultes survivent
> une dizaine de jours dans l’environnement, mais les oeufs de
> cheyletielles peuvent être aussi une source d’infestation
> pour une plus longue période. »,

> « ([EXPERTTSE MÉDICALE Docteur Evgeniy KACMAN Maladie infectieuse interne](https://fr.iliveok.com/health/les-acariens-mordent-chez-lhomme_109573i15955.html)
> ) La bosse sur le site de la piqûre de tique
> Souvent, le corps humain répond négativement à l'introduction d'une tique. Ainsi, l'endroit de la morsure commence à rougir, dans certains cas, il y a de la condensation. De tout cela se passe-t-il et y a-t-il un danger? Il faut comprendre qu'une réaction allergique ordinaire peut provoquer une bosse au site de la piqûre de tique. Il se produit en raison de la perforation de la peau par la trompe et de la pénétration de la salive. Et il n'est pas nécessaire que la salive soit infectée, même sous une forme stérile, elle peut provoquer une réaction allergique. »,

il s'ensuit que la *maladie de la mite baveuse* est  très probablement la maladie réelle appelée « cheyletiellose », et c'est l'injustice. C'est l'injustice *qui fait vantarder les pauvres gens après leurs bévues, leurs cagneries, leurs tares pustulantes d'infernaux*. Ce sont les erreurs (bévues) des pauvres gens, leurs « cagneries » ([pas encore expliqué]), et leurs tares  qui résultent en vantardise ([« vantarder » introuvable dans les dictionnaires, mais très probablement de sens « se vanter ») ; on voit plus loin que cette injustice, que Céline impute non pas seulement à un acte de la « caste » mais aussi à des erreurs des pauvres gens et des tares  dont ils sont affligés, résulte en des « guerres » ; il n'y a pas de doute que l'on a ici une description en règle de la lutte des classes ;  le mot « cagnerie » pourrait alors signifier « cagnardise », et pourrait être une invention de Céline. Il y a une certaine évidence qui porte à croire que ce pourrait être le sens à donner à ce mot introuvable dans les dictionnaires.

> ([Ac. 1ère édition, 1694](https://artfl.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/getobject_?p.1:58./var/artfla/dicos/ACAD_1694/IMAGE/)) **Cagnardise** s. f. Faineantise, lascheté. Il est bas

On retrouve cette idée de bassesse dans la phrase même, à sa fin : « c'est à vomir tellement qu'ils sont bas et tenaces ! »

> ([Ac. 9ème édition](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/cagnardise?page=1))  **Cagnardise**   xvie siècle. Dérivé de cagnard I. xvie siècle. Dérivé de cagnard I.
> Fam. Manière d'être du cagnard ; fainéantise. (I. CAGNARD, -ARDE adj.
> xvie siècle, cagnar, puis caignard, proprement « fainéant comme une chienne ». Dérivé de cagne, « chienne, mauvais chien » (xve siècle))
> Fam. Manière d'être du cagnard ; fainéantise.

L'idée de lâcheté se trouve encore dans cette définition du [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cagnard).

> cagnard \ka.ɲaʁ\
> 1.Qui s’accroupit comme un chien et ne bouge plus.
> 2.(Familier) Qui n’aime pas bouger, qui est paresseux.
> 3. (Populaire) (Vieilli) (Désuet) Qui est lâche, poltron.